# GCC (ARM) equivalent to __declspec(dllexport)

Tags: c++, gcc, arm, dllexport, visual-studio-2010

When building application for x86, the following code works fine:

```
#if   defined _WIN32
#define LIB_PRE __declspec(dllexport)
#elif defined __unix__
#define LIB_PRE
#else
#define LIB_PRE __declspec(dllexport)
#endif
```

But gives an error for GCC (ARM). I have found out that __declspec(dllexport) wont work on GCC. If so, what should I use for GCC (ARM)?

Edit:

Its used in many classes. e.g:

```
class CJsonValueString : public CJsonValue
{
 private:
  jstring value;
 public:
  LIB_PRE CJsonValueString(jstring value);
  LIB_PRE CJsonValueString(const CJsonValueString * value);
  LIB_PRE jstring ToString() const;
  LIB_PRE int ToInt() const;
  LIB_PRE int64 ToInt64 () const;
  LIB_PRE float ToFloat () const;
  LIB_PRE void GetValue(jstring & str) const;
};
```

Comment: Can you show an example usage of this macro?

Comment: You probably mean "for Windows/x86' since it **won't work on "Linux/x86"**

Comment: Also let me mention that `__declspec(dllexport)` works as intended on MinGW GCC on Windows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically, you probably don't need anything special. But if you want (and if working on shared objects, i.e. `*.so` files), learn more about [visibility pragmas](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Visibility-Pragmas.html) and visibility [function attributes](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#Function-Attributes)

And the question is more target operating system specific than target machine specific. (I would imagine that an ARM running some obscure Windows8/ARM system would also need your `__declspec`; conversely, your `__declspec` has no sense on Linux/x86).

Comment: Exaclty, Windows 8 probably also uses such attributes for ARM. I don't see why they wouldn't :)

Comment: In my very biased opinion, Windows design of DLLs is much worse than Linux shared libraries.

Comment: I personally like the explicit visibility MS enforces. It allows for a clean interface, although stuff like MYLIB_DLL defines pop up in the wild :/

Comment: In MINGW / GCC __declspec and visiblity pragmas can both occur, where the use of __declspec seems to suppress the visbility pragma, such that if one third party lib requires __declspec, all shall have it

Answer (score 5):

Here's a simplified version of what we use in our code.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#define EXTERNC         extern "C"
#else
#define EXTERNC
#endif

#if defined(__NT__)                   // MS Windows
  #define idaapi            __stdcall
  #define ida_export        idaapi
  #if defined(__IDP__)                  // modules
    #define idaman          EXTERNC
  #else                                 // kernel
    #if defined(__X64__) || defined(__NOEXPORT__)
      #define idaman          EXTERNC
    #else
      #define idaman          EXTERNC __declspec(dllexport)
    #endif
  #endif
  #define ida_local
#elif defined(__UNIX__)                 // for unix
  #define idaapi
  #if defined(__MAC__)
    #define idaman          EXTERNC __attribute__((visibility("default")))
    #define ida_local       __attribute__((visibility("hidden")))
  #else  // Linux
    #if __GNUC__ >= 4
      #define idaman          EXTERNC __attribute__ ((visibility("default")))
      #define ida_local       __attribute__((visibility("hidden")))
    #else
      #define idaman          EXTERNC
      #define ida_local
    #endif
  #endif
#endif
```

On Linux/OS X, we compile all code by default with `-fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden` and mark up stuff we want to export with `idaman`, e.g.

```
idaman bool ida_export set_enum_width(enum_t id, int width);
```

Since you're exporting C++ methods, you'll probably want to skip the `extern "C"` part.